# Grouping variables in a table in markdown with pdf knit

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable

I'm trying to create a table in my markdown document, that will group some variables, so that I can settle with using one table instead of creating two in the document.
I have four variable that needs to be incorporated in the table. First of all I have the "CandidateType" which determines the status of an applicant, then I have "Step" which determines the step achieved by a candidate in the recruitment process, and finally I have "Quarter" which determines which quarter of the year the data is from. The last variable is the numeric values.

When I only had one quarter, I simply used the following code to generate the table in my markdown document:

```
dfVis1Table <- xtabs(Total ~ CandidateType + Step, dfVis1)

kable(dfVis1Table)
```

However, with the "Quarter" variable, this isn't possible anymore, since I need the quarter variable to create a kind of grouping column above the table.

```
dfVis2Table <- xtabs(Total ~ CandidateType + Step + Quarter, dfVis2)

kable(dfVis2Table)
```

Result:

```
> kable(dfVis2Table)
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("Ansættelse", "Samtale")) : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
```

Is there any way to create a table with a grouping column on the top when making a pdf in markdown, or do you have to create a html instead and use htmlTable? I must admit that I haven't tried out pandoc.table, but I also have no idea if it is worth trying out at all in this instance?

My data:

```
, , Quarter = 4. quarter 2017

              Step
CandidateType Hired       Interview
     External 28.754098   9.097510
     Internal  4.090909   2.006369

, , Quarter = YTD 2018

              Step
CandidateType Hired      Interview
     External 115.886076  10.808737
     Internal   8.906977   2.697183
```

Comment: Check out the [`kableExtra`](https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra) package.

Comment: Hi Jake, are you thinking about any specific function? And can you maybe give an example? Thanks a lot

Comment: I included a link in there, and if you review the README, it gives a very good walkthrough on making the tables you're interested in.